# Changing character direction based on touch value

Tags: ios, loops, sprite-kit, swift4, increment

I have a control in my game so that a character rotates to 45 degrees when touched.x < 0 and -45 when touch.x > 0

```
    if touched.x < 0 {
        getawaycar.zRotation = CGFloat(.pi/4.0);
    }

    if touched.x > 0 {
        getawaycar.zRotation = CGFloat(-(.pi/4.0));
    }
```

So if I slide my finger to

```
CGPoint(x: touched.x, y: 0)
```

Getawaycar rotates to the left. But as soon as I slide my finger towards are more positive x value I want the Getwawaycar to rotate towards the right.

Comment: What function is this code in? What actually happens compared to what you want to happen? What is `touched`? is that where on the screen you touched or where on the character?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this way?

```
  if touched.x < 0 {
        getawaycar.zRotation = CGFloat(.pi/4.0);
    } else {
        getawaycar.zRotation = CGFloat(-(.pi/4.0));
    }
```